# make knockout array object visible based on an id value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, knockout.js

All the examples I see are for DOM elements that are explicitly written on the page. In my case I am using the knockout foreach to create a list of items in my observable array:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="recruiting">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: selectedOrgKey" id="orgSectionId" onchange="FlipOrgView()" style="visibility: hidden;" />
    <ul class="list-unstyled" data-bind="foreach: orgs">
        <li data-bind="attr: { id: 'orgSection' + orgId}" class="orgSection">
```

I am currently using a kludgy solution by using the onchange on an hidden element to grab the id and .show() it.

```
window.OrgDdlUpdated = function () {
    $(".orgSection").hide();
    var selectedOrgId = $('#orgDropDown').val();
    //alert(selectedOrgId);
    flipOrgView(selectedOrgId);
};

var flipOrgView = function (id) {
    $('#orgSection' + id).show();
};
```

This technically works, the first time, but as I flip through it all, the selected id lags behind to where it shows the previous selection, not the current one. I know there are various ways to achieve this, so knockout or otherwise, how can i properly toggle the visibility of an array of objects using the knockout foreach method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="recruiting">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: selectedOrgKey" id="orgSectionId" style="visibility: hidden;" />
    <ul class="list-unstyled" data-bind="foreach: orgs">
        <li data-bind="visible: $parent.selectedOrgKey() === orgId(), attr: { id: 'orgSection' + orgId}" class="orgSection">
```

im not too sure in your example how you are setting selectedOrgKey but this should do the MVVM behavior i think you are getting at.

Comment: Ah, thank you. This one was killing my brain. Or lack of brain.

Comment: @davidisawesome np glad to help :)